# Prevent user to use back button or control the action it will make

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm coding an app where the user needs to decode a word the app has previously encoded. The user has exactly 120 seconds to guess as many words as possible. Here is my code :

```
@app.route('/c_cesar', methods=['GET','POST'])
def c_cesar():
    global points, word, shift, time
    if request.method=='GET':
        init_classe()
        cesar_game(points+1, randint(points+1, 2*points+1))
    elif request.method=='POST' and request.content_type!='application/json':
        cesar_game(points+1, randint(points+1, 2*points+1))
        time=time-1 if time>0 else time
        iptword=request.form['word']
        if cryptage.cesar(iprword, shift[0])==word[0]:
            points+=1
    else:
        time=request.get_json()
    if time==0:
        uploadScore()
    return render_template('c_cesar.html', word=word[1], shift=shift[1], points=points, time=time)
```

```
var display=document.getElementById('display');
var time=parseInt(display.innerHTML,10);
display.innerHTML=time;

function timing() {
    if (time>0) {
        time--;
        display.innerHTML=time;
        $.ajax({
            url:"/c_cesar",
            type:"POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(time)});
        }
    else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        window.location='/';
    }
}

var timer=setInterval(timing, 1000);
```

But when the user clicks on the back button, the timer jumps back to when it posted its previous guess. A user could easily go back and cheat the game...
I was wondering if it was possible to prevent user from clicking the back button, or better, control where it will be redirected...

Answer (score -1):

***USE WITH CSS !!!***

Use the **opacity** property to add transparency to a button (creates a "disabled" look).

**Tip:** You can also add the cursor property with a value of "not-allowed", which will display a "no parking sign" when you mouse over the button:

```
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: You can't affect the browser's back button with CSS.